# Numeric variable exported to Excel is converted to a String variable in R

Tags: r, excel, export, character, na

I am trying to export a data frame from R to Excel using the write.xlsx2 function as follows:

```
 write.xlsx2(gamdf3, file="directory/filename.xlsx", sheetName='sheetname', col.names = TRUE, 
  rowNames=FALSE, append = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE)
```

The export produces the file but many of the numeric variables are converted to character or string variables in the resultant Excel file.

When I perform the same export using the write.csv function the format of the variables is correct i.e. all numeric variables are numeric (no quotation marks, etc.). I believe the problem is related to the fact that Excel is recognizing NA values as strings and as a resort imports any columns with NAs as character variables. Does anyone have any other ideas and/or potential solutions to the problem?

**The long term goal of the code I am writing is to create a program to output multiple data frames to multiple Sheets within the same Excel spreadsheet file so writing to .csv is not an option.**

Here is the structure of the data file:

```
structure(list(rowID = 1:15, date = structure(c(885427200, 886291200, 
887155200, 888019200, 888883200, 889747200, 890611200, 891475200, 
892339200, 893203200, 894067200, 894931200, 895795200, 896659200, 
897523200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), year = c(1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 
1998, 1998), cyear = c(-12.4412568306011, -12.4139344262296, 
-12.3866120218579, -12.3592896174864, -12.3292349726776, -12.3019125683061, 
-12.2745901639344, -12.2472677595629, -12.2199453551914, -12.1926229508197, 
-12.1653005464482, -12.1379781420765, -12.110655737705, -12.0833333333335, 
-12.0560109289618), doy = c(21, 31, 41, 51, 62, 72, 82, 92, 102, 
112, 122, 132, 142, 152, 162), doy.actual = c(21, 31, 41, 51, 
62, 72, 82, 92, 102, 112, 122, 132, 142, 152, 162), intervention = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), intervention.actual = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), flw_sal = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    flw_sal.sd = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), pred1 = structure(c(-3.17329212088662, 
    -3.17551593672685, -3.15581665295864, -3.11333361725085, 
    -3.05024545221121, -2.99455893265757, -2.95636216080379, 
    -2.94581946702954, -2.95546503981884, -2.97336405071292, 
    -2.98574203230184, -2.97858219526318, -2.94331362759408, 
    -2.88597790777411, -2.81509202061218), dim = 15L), se1 = structure(c(0.116576033335553, 
    0.111273729473221, 0.107619106375585, 0.104120549185184, 
    0.101475564182619, 0.101964784351847, 0.103461688538075, 
    0.103096127689722, 0.101492745585798, 0.100207114968191, 
    0.0995128325685113, 0.0979957687059049, 0.09568626951097, 
    0.0954791786979895, 0.097038449656865), dim = 15L), seas.1 = structure(c(-3.11049016661174, 
    -3.11139927969704, -3.11230934020399, -3.11322140430994, 
    -3.11422862446344, -3.11514989240917, -3.11607849270063, 
    -3.1170166555304, -3.11796691854529, -3.11893183276051, -3.11991398109568, 
    -3.12091618226964, -3.12194136068752, -3.12299244125247, 
    -3.12407234886761), dim = 15L), seas.2 = structure(c(-2.93150018520574, 
    -2.93350692124891, -2.9355146004977, -2.93752427442632, -2.93973884749874, 
    -2.94175768303456, -2.9437838165952, -2.94581946702954, -2.94786715857577, 
    -2.94992942875071, -2.95200884662885, -2.95410821452131, 
    -2.95623043927691, -2.95837842823712, -2.96055508874333), dim = 15L), 
    seas.3 = structure(c(-2.64136901037537, -2.64198370245015, 
    -2.64259933903913, -2.64321697307644, -2.64390030783014, 
    -2.64452711662482, -2.64516123415242, -2.64580488282911, 
    -2.64646059112389, -2.64713090081328, -2.64781838534573, 
    -2.64852585225076, -2.64925621397411, -2.65001238345593, 
    -2.65079727363629), dim = 15L), seas.4 = structure(c(-2.37763852898549, 
    -2.37782955449868, -2.3780215260613, -2.37821549832011, -2.37843281163773, 
    -2.37863597406244, -2.37884645775752, -2.37906648930311, 
    -2.3792986021004, -2.37954534289148, -2.37980929022138, -2.38009325768437, 
    -2.38040016422485, -2.38073292928368, -2.38109447230166), dim = 15L), 
    seasMeanMin = c(-2.64136901037537, -2.64198370245015, -2.64259933903913, 
    -2.64321697307644, -2.64390030783014, -2.64452711662482, 
    -2.64516123415242, -2.64580488282911, -2.64646059112389, 
    -2.64713090081328, -2.64781838534573, -2.64852585225076, 
    -2.64925621397411, -2.65001238345593, -2.65079727363629), 
    seasMeanMax = c(-2.41297963576283, -2.41326209813037, -2.4135455055776, 
    -2.41383091166952, -2.41414879808664, -2.41444338461832, 
    -2.41474528450996, -2.41505672171899, -2.41538022654228, 
    -2.41571834259667, -2.41607364522027, -2.4164489441968, -2.41684715438958, 
    -2.41727119115708, -2.41772396985774), seasMeanMean = c(-2.52724949149686, 
    -2.52768549428506, -2.52812244188445, -2.52856138756047, 
    -2.52904816637882, -2.52949628979597, -2.5299517243754, -2.53041669334214, 
    -2.53089372612433, -2.53138536546414, -2.5318941858015, -2.53242299584829, 
    -2.53297470931812, -2.53355224041944, -2.53415850336061), 
    pred1.adjusted = structure(c(-3.11706684644201, -3.11929066228224, 
    -3.09959137851403, -3.05710834280624, -2.9940201777666, -2.93833365821296, 
    -2.90013688635918, -2.88959419258493, -2.89923976537423, 
    -2.91713877626831, -2.92951675785723, -2.92235692081857, 
    -2.88708835314947, -2.8297526333295, -2.75886674616757), dim = 15L), 
    seas.1.adjusted = structure(c(-3.05426489216713, -3.05517400525243, 
    -3.05608406575938, -3.05699612986533, -3.05800335001883, 
    -3.05892461796457, -3.05985321825602, -3.06079138108579, 
    -3.06174164410068, -3.0627065583159, -3.06368870665107, -3.06469090782503, 
    -3.06571608624291, -3.06676716680787, -3.06784707442301), dim = 15L), 
    seas.2.adjusted = structure(c(-2.87527491076113, -2.8772816468043, 
    -2.87928932605309, -2.88129899998171, -2.88351357305413, 
    -2.88553240858995, -2.88755854215059, -2.88959419258493, 
    -2.89164188413116, -2.8937041543061, -2.89578357218424, -2.8978829400767, 
    -2.9000051648323, -2.90215315379251, -2.90432981429873), dim = 15L), 
    seas.3.adjusted = structure(c(-2.58514373593076, -2.58575842800554, 
    -2.58637406459452, -2.58699169863183, -2.58767503338553, 
    -2.58830184218021, -2.58893595970781, -2.5895796083845, -2.59023531667929, 
    -2.59090562636867, -2.59159311090112, -2.59230057780615, 
    -2.59303093952951, -2.59378710901132, -2.59457199919169), dim = 15L), 
    seas.4.adjusted = structure(c(-2.32141325454088, -2.32160428005408, 
    -2.32179625161669, -2.3219902238755, -2.32220753719312, -2.32241069961784, 
    -2.32262118331291, -2.3228412148585, -2.32307332765579, -2.32332006844688, 
    -2.32358401577678, -2.32386798323976, -2.32417488978024, 
    -2.32450765483907, -2.32486919785705), dim = 15L), seasMeandoyAdj.183 = structure(c(-2.58514373593076, 
    -2.58575842800554, -2.58637406459452, -2.58699169863183, 
    -2.58767503338553, -2.58830184218021, -2.58893595970781, 
    -2.5895796083845, -2.59023531667929, -2.59090562636867, -2.59159311090112, 
    -2.59230057780615, -2.59303093952951, -2.59378710901132, 
    -2.59457199919169), dim = 15L), seasMeandoyAdj.190 = structure(c(-2.53041101592029, 
    -2.53092589222394, -2.53144171320235, -2.53195953196875, 
    -2.53253307060658, -2.53306006574279, -2.53359437092446, 
    -2.53413820900437, -2.53469410896905, -2.53526461311607, 
    -2.53585229542878, -2.53645996407412, -2.53709053218116, 
    -2.5377469133736, -2.53843202127508), dim = 15L), seasMeandoyAdj.197 = structure(c(-2.47575338304226, 
    -2.47618264450966, -2.47661285079232, -2.47704505516023, 
    -2.47752441855683, -2.47796580070627, -2.47841449405059, 
    -2.47887272182534, -2.47934301347091, -2.47982791174184, 
    -2.48032999109066, -2.48085206024388, -2.48139703293061, 
    -2.4819678233748, -2.48256734580034), dim = 15L), seasMeandoyAdj.206 = structure(c(-2.40705858904971, 
    -2.40739731077736, -2.40773697747702, -2.40807864259359, 
    -2.40845841348006, -2.40880925795382, -2.40916741490574, 
    -2.40953510799908, -2.40991486718171, -2.41030923571903, 
    -2.41072078858824, -2.41115233514206, -2.41160678978133, 
    -2.41208706740196, -2.41259608289976), dim = 15L), seasMeandoyAdj.213 = structure(c(-2.35675436131822, 
    -2.35703682368576, -2.35732023113299, -2.35760563722491, 
    -2.35792352364203, -2.35821811017371, -2.35852001006536, 
    -2.35883144727438, -2.35915495209767, -2.35949306815206, 
    -2.35984837077566, -2.36022366975219, -2.36062187994497, 
    -2.36104591671247, -2.36149869541313), dim = 15L), seasMeanMin.adjusted = c(-2.58514373593076, 
    -2.58575842800554, -2.58637406459452, -2.58699169863183, 
    -2.58767503338553, -2.58830184218021, -2.58893595970781, 
    -2.5895796083845, -2.59023531667929, -2.59090562636867, -2.59159311090112, 
    -2.59230057780615, -2.59303093952951, -2.59378710901132, 
    -2.59457199919169), seasMeanMax.adjusted = c(-2.35675436131822, 
    -2.35703682368576, -2.35732023113299, -2.35760563722491, 
    -2.35792352364203, -2.35821811017371, -2.35852001006536, 
    -2.35883144727438, -2.35915495209767, -2.35949306815206, 
    -2.35984837077566, -2.36022366975219, -2.36062187994497, 
    -2.36104591671247, -2.36149869541313), seasMeanMean.adjusted = c(-2.47102421705225, 
    -2.47146021984045, -2.47189716743984, -2.47233611311586, 
    -2.47282289193421, -2.47327101535136, -2.47372644993079, 
    -2.47419141889754, -2.47466845167973, -2.47516009101953, 
    -2.47566891135689, -2.47619772140368, -2.47674943487352, 
    -2.47732696597483, -2.477933228916), sa.pred1 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), dim = c(15L, 1L)), sa.se1 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), dim = c(15L, 1L)), sad = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), dim = c(15L, 1L)), sad.se = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), dim = c(15L, 1L)), ciub = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), dim = c(15L, 1L)), cilb = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), dim = c(15L, 1L)), ndate = c(885427200, 
    886291200, 887155200, 888019200, 888883200, 889747200, 890611200, 
    891475200, 892339200, 893203200, 894067200, 894931200, 895795200, 
    896659200, 897523200), sadz = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), dim = c(15L, 1L)), sadzp = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), dim = c(15L, 1L)), sa.pred1.sig = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), dim = c(15L, 1L)), sa.pred1.adjusted = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), dim = c(15L, 1L)), sa.se1.adjusted = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), dim = c(15L, 1L))), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I cant recreate this issue on my end. Can you edit your question to provide the output of `dput(gamdf3)`?

Comment: jpsmith Well I'm not sure exactly how to do that since the file is 900 rows and 44 variables.  :) It must be something else. Here is the problem I think I did an str on the object that contained the export file and the numeric variables with the problems have num [1:909(1d)] and num  [1:909, 1] formats rather than just num formats. Any ideas as to what this means?

Comment: you can add a snippet of your data with with `dput(gamdf3[1:15, ])`

Comment: Maybe using the openxlsx::write.xlsx() function would work better. The xlsx package is a bit buggy for me.

Comment: Nope no difference ...thanks anyway